# Using JUnit 4 with HierarchicalContextRunner and JUnitParamsRunner

Tags: java, junit, junit-runner

I want to create the following test class with JUnit4:

```
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import de.bechte.junit.runners.context.HierarchicalContextRunner;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
@RunWith(HierarchicalContextRunner.class)
public class MultipleRunWithTest {
   //...
}
```

I want to use both facilities of `HierarchicalContextRunner` and `JUnitParamsRunner`, because they are handy in creating readable unit tests.
JUnit gives this compile error:

```
Duplicate annotation @RunWith   MultipleRunWith.java
```

What could be a resonable solution?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no way in JUnit to use two runners at a time. I think this would require refactoring the JUnit core into some kind of event-based execution framework that allows interception of the request at several extension points.

So for me, there is no way to do this right now. I hope that the hierarchical context runner will replace the default runner some time. Then everything should be fine. ;-)

All the best,
Stefan